# justin.tv jquery get some data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, stream, justin.tv

I've been reading for hours on this json stuff and the justin.tv API documenation but still unable to get the number of viewers currently viewing my stream.

Here's a json script I tried, nothing happens.

```
    var url = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json";

    $.ajax({
       url: url,
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       data: { channel: "dreamvoid"},
       success: function(data) { $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(data.stream_count)); },
       jsonp: 'jsonp'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is returning `JSON`, not `JSONP`. Please refer to the justin.tv api documentation to get it to return proper `JSONP`. If you cannot get it to return `JSONP`, you will need to either use YQL or implement a server-side proxy to make the request for you.

Also, `JSON.stringify(data.stream_count)` should be `data.stream_count`.